# Highlight text with RegExp unicode in javascript

Tags: regex, highlight

I am using

```
var abc = new RegExp(`(?:\\b)(${tag_content[i].tag_content})(?:\\b)`, "gi"); 
var newStr = innerHTML.replace(abc, '<span style="background-color:#1de4bd; color:#fff;">$1</span>');
```

But unicode does not work when replaced.

Please help me? :(

Comment: Please, give us example inputs with expected outputs so with can help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
const array  = ["Dân số","Điện","Thành Thị", ...];
const stringHtml = "Dân số hiện nay của đất nước ....";
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
var abc = new RegExp(`(?=[\\b^\p{L}\p{M}])(${array[i]})(?=[^\p{L}\p{M}$]\\b)`, "gi");
var newStr = stringHtml.replace(abc, '<span style="background-color:#1de4bd; color:#fff;">$1</span>');
}
```

I want get output newStr replace unicode.